# Django transaction isolation level in mysql & postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, isolation-level

Do you know the default isolation level of the transactions used in Django?
Is it possible to set the isolation level in the database independent way?

I'm mainly interested in mysql and postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isolation level isn't changed by mysql drivers so it depends on the server's default isolation level.

Answer (score 10):

You can also change this per client / session using the django database options, like this:

```
DATABASE_OPTIONS = { "init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB, SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED", }
```

Comment: Someone can confirm that this runs? I have problems with repeatable read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235318/how-do-i-deal-with-this-race-condition-in-django

Comment: @danihp definitely runs, although the syntax is is off. I'm using `SET storage_engine=INNODB; SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;` instead

Answer (score 4):

At the moment django does not set the isolation level. This is a bug, because of django does not work properly with any higher isolation level than READ COMMITTED. But MySQL is using REPEATABLE READ by default. There are plans to add a setting to set the isolation level ([#14026](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14026)) and a discussion about making READ COMMITTED the default ([#13906](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13906)). I have also written a detailed article about [MySQL transactions and django](https://web.archive.org/web/20120716043634/http://www.no-ack.org/2010/07/mysql-transactions-and-django.html).

Comment: Thanks, but the blog you've linked to seems to be private. Could you open that article, or copy/paste here?

Comment: Can you pls cite some info or elaborate about  "django does not work properly with any higher isolation level than READ COMMITTED".

Comment: @Sebastian Noack The article says 'Permission Needed'?

Comment: I found this article that refers to this private article and actually has content you can read: http://www.ewencp.org/blog/django-and-mysql-isolation-levels/

Comment: I believe it has to do with how Django used to emulate auto-commit instead of using database level auto-commit. This has been fixed in Django 1.6: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#autocommit-details

Answer (score 2):

According to my test, Django's default isolation level depends on the isolation level which you set for your database. In other words, if you set `SERIALIZABLE` for your PostgreSQL or MySQL, Django's default isolation level is `SERIALIZABLE`.

And, to set `SERIALIZABLE` for PostgreSQL, I tried what [**the documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#isolation-level) explains in `settings.py` in **Django 3.2.16** on **Windows 11** as shown below but it didn't work so the isolation level is still `READ COMMITTED`:

```py
# "settings.py"

import psycopg2.extensions

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    },
    'OPTIONS': { # ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Doesn't work ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
        'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
    },
}
```

But, I could set and check `SERIALIZABLE` by running the raw queries in `settings.py` for PostgreSQL as shown below. *Run the raw queries after [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases) in `settings.py`:

```py
# "settings.py"

from django.db import connection

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    },
}

# ↓ ↓ ↓ Set isolation level ↓ ↓ ↓

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """
        ALTER DATABASE postgres 
        SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION 
        TO 'SERIALIZABLE';
        """
cursor.execute(query)

# ↓ ↓ ↓ Check isolation level ↓ ↓ ↓

cursor.execute('SHOW default_transaction_isolation;')
print(cursor.fetchone()) # ('serializable',)
```

*Or, you can directly set `SERIALIZABLE` with **psql** as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE postgres SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION TO 'SERIALIZABLE';
```

And for MySQL, you will be able to set and check `SERIALIZABLE` by running the raw queries in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

from django.db import connection

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# ↓ ↓ ↓ Set isolation level ↓ ↓ ↓

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """
        SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
        """
cursor.execute(query)

# ↓ ↓ ↓ Check isolation level ↓ ↓ ↓

cursor.execute('SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation;')
print(cursor.fetchone()) # ('serializable',)
```

*Or, you can directly set `SERIALIZABLE` with **MySQL client** as shown below:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, i can't comment for Danhip)
This solution wotked for me (mySQL), I added Peter's code in the DATABASE field:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        (...)
        'OPTIONS': {
            (...),
            "init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB, SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED"
        },
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use read uncommited isolation level.

you add the 'isolation_level': 'read uncommitted' in 'OPTIONS on database connection configuration.

```html
DATABASES = {
    'read-uncommited': {
        'OPTIONS': {
            'isolation_level': 'read uncommitted'
        },
    },
}
```

you can find from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/