# Does django create implicit transaction on first query?

Tags: sql, django, transactions, innodb

I have django 1.3.1, python2.6 and MySQL 5.5.20.
`init_command` in setting.py is set to `SET storage_engine=INNODB`.

I have the following situation:

Consider the model:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I open two Django shells and type:

**django shell I:**

```
./manage.py shell
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import fruits.models as m
>>> m.Fruit(name="apple").save()
>>> m.Fruit.objects.get(pk=1)    
<Fruit: apple>
```

**django shell II:**

```
./manage.py shell
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import fruits.models as m
>>> m.Fruit.objects.get(pk=1)    
<Fruit: apple>
```

So far so good. Now I continue to type in **shell I**:

```
>>> m.Fruit(name="peach").save()
>>> m.Fruit.objects.get(pk=2)
<Fruit: peach>
```

**Qestion: Why typing the following in the** ***shell II***  **does not find the object?**

```
>>> m.Fruit.objects.get(pk=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "..../django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "..../django/db/models/query.py", line 349, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Fruit matching query does not exist.
```

The only way I've found to make shell II to have "a fresh look" is this:

```
>>> from django.db import transaction
>>> transaction.enter_transaction_management()
>>> transaction.rollback()
```

And I need to `roolback()` each time I query for fruits if I want to be sure that orm will not "lie".

Comment: You can relax isolation level to read commited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280779/django-transaction-isolation-level-in-mysql-postgresql (see Peter Lundberg answer)

Comment: But "peach" is committed. If I exit shell 2 and run it again, I'll see it

Comment: @danihp, yes you are actually right. This is MySQL issue and django one's. Please write this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a issolation issue. You can relax to 'isolation level read commited' to avoid this behavior. Also, learn about this issolation level implications ([phantoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Phantom_reads)).

To set Read Commited Isolation Level into MySQL for your django project you should set this parameter in settings.py:

```
DATABASE_OPTIONS = { 
     "init_command": 'SET storage_engine=INNODB,    \
                      SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED', }
```

Comment: As a note, current MySQL isolation level can be checked using the following: `select @@session.tx_isolation;`

Comment: Can you give an example of "concurrency exception"?

Comment: A concurrency exception is raised when two users attempt to change the same data in a database at the same time. Is more complex than this: each isolation level has different rules, a transaction can handle several data changes, etc.

Comment: Remember that exists auto commit decorator that is also a solution to your issue: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/transactions/#django-db-transaction-autocommit

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: Its not enough to set init_command in settings.py - in **celery** it does not seem to be applied, so isolation level should be set on database-wide level.