# difference between objects.create() and object.save() in django orm

Tags: python, django, orm

```
u = UserDetails.objects.create(first_name='jake',last_name='sullivan')
u.save()
```

`UserDetails.objects.create()` and `u.save()` both perform the same `save()` function. What is the difference? Is there any extra check or benefit in using `create()` vs `save()`?

Similar questions:

- [What's the best way to create a model object in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624075/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-model-object-in-django)
- [Django: Difference between save() and create() from transaction perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206819/django-difference-between-save-and-create-from-transaction-perspective)
- [Django Model() vs Model.objects.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672077/django-model-vs-model-objects-create)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[The Django documentation says it is the same](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#create). It is just **more convenient** to make it on one line. You could make a `save()` on one line too, but it would be more verbose and less readable -- it is clear you are creating a new object with the `create()` method.

> #### `create(**kwargs)`
>
> A convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one
>   step. Thus:
>
> ```
> p = Person.objects.create(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> p = Person(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
> p.save(force_insert=True)
> ```
>
> are equivalent.
>
> The `force_insert` parameter is documented elsewhere, but all it means
>   is that a new object will always be created. Normally you won’t need
>   to worry about this. However, if your model contains a manual primary
>   key value that you set and if that value already exists in the
>   database, a call to `create()` will fail with an `IntegrityError` since
>   primary keys must be unique. Be prepared to handle the exception if
>   you are using manual primary keys.

Comment: Just a reminder to everyone, both `create` and `save` do not check that the data is valid, you still need to call `full_clean`.

Answer (score 17):

Similar question:
[Django Model() vs Model.objects.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672077/django-model-vs-model-objects-create)

The difference between `Model()` vs `Model.objects.create()` are summarized as below.

---

1. `.save()` perform internally as either **INSERT** or **UPDATE** object to db, while `.objects.create()` perform only **INSERT** object to db.

   `Model.save()`  perform **....**

   **UPDATE** → If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates to `True`

   **INSERT** →
   If the object’s primary key attribute is not set or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything (e.g. if primary key is set to a value that doesn’t exist in the database).

---

2. If primary key attribute is set to a value then `Model.save()` perform **UPDATE** but `Model.objects.create` raise `IntegrityError`.

   eg.

   **models.py**

   ```
   class Subject(models.Model):
      subject_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='subject_id')
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      max_marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   ```

   **1) Insert/Update to db with `Model.save()`**

   ```
   physics = Subject(subject_id=1, name='Physics', max_marks=100)
   physics.save()
   math = Subject(subject_id=1, name='Math', max_marks=50)  # Case of update
   math.save()
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Subject.objects.all().values()
   <QuerySet [{'subject_id': 1, 'name': 'Math', 'max_marks': 50}]>
   ```

   **2) Insert to db with `Model.objects.create()`**

   ```
   Subject.objects.create(subject_id=1, name='Chemistry', max_marks=100)
   IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: m****t.subject_id
   ```

   **Explanation:** Above `math.save()` is case of update since `subject_id` is primary key and `subject_id=1` exists django internally perform **UPDATE**, *name Physics to Math and max_marks from 100 to 50* for this, but `objects.create() raise IntegrityError`

---

3. `Model.objects.create()` not equivalent to `Model.save()` however same can be achieved with `force_insert=True` parameter on `save` method i.e `Model.save(force_insert=True)`.

---

4. `Model.save()` return `None` where `Model.objects.create()` return model instance i.e. `package_name.models.Model`

---

**Conclusion:** `Model.objects.create()` internally do model initialization and perform `save` with `force_insert=True`.

source-code block of Model.objects.create()

```
def create(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
    and returning the created object.
    """
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    self._for_write = True
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    return obj
```

The following links can be followed for more details:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#create
2. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2d8dcba03aae200aaa103ec1e69f0a0038ec2f85/django/db/models/query.py#L440

**Note:** Above answer is from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672077/django-model-vs-model-objects-create).

Answer (score 0):

My thought on this is that you should user=User.objects.create(name=name, location=location) for instance when creating a new User object and use an instance of user.save() when you are modifying the user object.