# Why am I getting duplicate key integrity errors from Django's get_or_create?

Tags: python, mysql, django, innodb, mysql-error-1062

**UPDATE:** Found the answer here, and the suggested work-around works for me: [How do I deal with this race condition in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235318/how-do-i-deal-with-this-race-condition-in-django)

Hello all.  Observe the following code:

```
while True:
    User.objects.get_or_create(email='foo-%d@example.com' % int(time()))
```

Where User is a standard Django model with unique=True for email.  When I run this code in two shells at the same time within a few seconds I get an error like:

```
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'foo-1292519049@example.com' for key 'email'")
```

It was my impression that get_or_create() was specifically designed to avoid this situation.  Looking at the code it seems to me that it should be working.  It does a get() first, then if that fails enters a transaction and tries a save().  If that fails it rolls back and tries a get() again.  If that fails then the exception from the save() is thrown, which seems to be what I'm getting.

Some useful info - I'm running Django v1.1.0 with MySQL v5.1.39 and InnoDB.  Our InnoDB isolation level is REPEATABLE-READ.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Man, this is ugly. Quick end dirty: use a shared lock before and release after the operation.