# How to fix concurrency in Django's get_or_create() leading to data duplication

Tags: django, concurrency, nginx

I have quite a complex issue that is causing duplicate records in my database.

I am running on nginx 1.0.5 with uwsgi (4 workers), and Django 1.4.5. The problem is that some clients are issueing duplicate requests for the same path, like shown by nginx log below:

```
10.205.132.51 - - [26/Aug/2013:16:59:41 -0300] "GET /path/to/ HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://mydomain.com.br/path/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
10.205.132.51 - - [26/Aug/2013:16:59:41 -0300] "GET /path/to/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7372 "http://mydomain.com.br/path/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
```

These requests are being processed simultaneously, and in cases like this view below, I am entering a race condition, where **both `get_or_create` find no results and both create a new object**:

```
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    f, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
        key1=value1,
        key2=value2,
        defaults={...})
```

Before you ask, no, these two keys are not `unique_together` in the database.

Both request return `200` status code from Django, however nginx discards one, resulting in a `409` status code (Conflict). The `transaction.commit_on_success()` part was an attempt that reduced, but didn't solve the issue.

I've also tried a cache-based lock, using this function:

```
@contextmanager
def cache_exclusive(name, timeout=10):
    """ found at http://coffeeonthekeyboard.com/simple-out-of-process-lock-with-python-and-memcached-2-985/ """
    key = 'cache_lock:%s' % name
    lock = cache.add(key, True, timeout=timeout)  # Fails if key already exists.
    yield lock  # Tell the inner block if it acquired the lock.
    if lock:  # Only clear the lock if we had it.
        cache.delete(key)
```

And a unique name with this usage:

```
    with cache_exclusive('key1 and key2') as granted:
        if not granted:
            return
        # do the get_or_create stuff...
```

But that also didn't nail it. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle these duplicate requests?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Forgot to mention that. It's mysql with InnoDB engine.

Comment: Maybe you also want to share what you are trying to achieve as there might be another solution to the problem as solving it on the database level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database. However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together), this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.
>
> If you are using MySQL, be sure to use the READ COMMITTED isolation level rather than REPEATABLE READ (the default), otherwise you may see cases where get_or_create will raise an IntegrityError but the object won’t appear in a subsequent get() call.
>
> Finally, a word on using get_or_create() in Django views: please make sure to use it only in POST requests unless you have a good reason not to GET requests shouldn’t have any effect on data; use POST whenever a request to a page as a side effect on your data. For more, see Safe methods in the HTTP spec.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 0):

```
 @transaction.commit_on_success
 def my_get_or_create(...):
     try:
         obj = MyObj.objects.create(...)
     except IntegrityError:
         transaction.commit()
         obj = MyObj.objects.get(...)
     return obj
```

[as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235318/how-do-i-deal-with-this-race-condition-in-django)