# Django threadsafe get_or_create with an external connection

Tags: mysql, django, multithreading, thread-safety, greenlets

Let's say I have a replacement `get_or_create` method in line with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2235624/1303955), except I need to combine this database transaction with an external API call (checking for the existence of an S3 bucket). **Assume that there is a unique constraint at the database level (MySQL InnoDB).** I'm running this code within multiple Gunicorn worker processes using eventlet.

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def get_or_create_with_func(obj, func_to_call=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        result, created = obj.objects.create(**kwargs), True
    except IntegrityError:
        transaction.commit()
        result, created = obj.objects.get(**kwargs), False

    func_result = None
    if func_to_call is not None and created:
        func_result = func_to_call()

    return result, created, func_result
```

The success of the transaction is contingent upon `func_to_call` returning successfully (without raising an exception). If it raises an exception, obviously the transaction will rollback.

What I'm unsure of is if 2 threads are using this function at the same time, will `create` still save an entry to the database (so that `IntegrityError` is raised and the `get` call returns an object), or will it have to "wait" until `func_to_call` finishes?

Essentially I'm imagining this scenario, with the function above called like this:

```
query_result, created, func_result = get_or_create_with_func(MyModel, external_api_func, model_column=some_value)
```

1. Thread 1 and 2 both call `get_or_create_with_func` at around the same time.
2. They both try creating the entry via `obj.objects.create`
3. Let's say thread 1 successfully creates it. It then exits the try/except block and then executes `func_to_call`.
4. Thread 2 tries creating the object as well.
5. Ideally, thread 2 will encounter an `IntegrityError`.
6. Thread 1 finishes calling `func_to_call`, it does not raise an exception.
7. Thread 2 "commits" (and Thread 1 has already finished committing as well), so it can call `get`, and gets the DB object written by Thread 1 as expected.

OR

6. Thread 1 calls `func_to_call` **and an exception is raised**.
7. Thread 1 causes django to rollback the transaction, so the DB entry does not exist.
8. Thread 2 should hopefully still encounter an `IntegrityError`, but now calling `get` won't return any object since Thread 1 rolled back the transaction.

My question is, on step #4, will `create` fail due to the unique constraint on the table, or will it go through since Thread 1 hasn't actually committed the transaction yet (let's say `func_to_call` is fairly slow)?