# How to monitor mysql table change in django?

Tags: mysql, django, monitor

In order to monitor mysql table change in django, I have written some codes as follows,

```
while not find_close_signal():
    time.sleep(10)
    if MyProject.models.MyModel.objects.all().exists():
        some_execution()
```

However, it doesn't work. If there is no entries in the table at the beginning, then some_execution() will never run even later there are records populated into that table through other out-band ways.

Does anyone ever meet such kind of issue?

I also found in "manage.py shell", this problem happens exactly the same: any other entries added into db out of this shell can not be found in this shell. Is this true or I've made some mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my answers here:

[Why doesn't this loop display an updated object count every five seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221247/why-doesnt-this-loop-display-an-updated-object-count-every-five-seconds/2221400#2221400)

[How do I deal with this race condition in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235318/how-do-i-deal-with-this-race-condition-in-django/2235624#2235624)

Answer (score 1):

not sure that this is an issue, but it may be that you have this code executed inside a transaction, so in such a case you can't see any changes.

one more thing is that you can skip ".all()" in this check.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the db as '[dirty](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/#transactions-and-raw-sql)' so to make Django discarding cached results:

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.set_dirty()
```